# How to read a REG_MULTI_SZ type value from the registry using RegQueryValueEx(..) in c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, registry

In our vc++ win32 application we are reading a registry value of type reg_multi_sz, its working fine on 32-bit but giving empty buffer when i ran on 64- bit. How can I read values of 64 bit registry from my 32-bit application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be more specific? Usually when your try to read 64-bit registry hive in 32-bit code you must open HKLM\Software using KEY_WOW64_64KEY. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much using this KEY_WOW64_64KEY access right its working fine onn 32 and 64 bit registry.

Comment: But want to know a bit more on this can you pls give why it failed before?

Comment: On 64 bit version of Windows parts of the registry are stored seperately for 32-bit apps and 64 bit apps. KEY_WOW64_64KEY will enable explicit access to the 64-bit view. Unless I look at more of your code I won't be able tell exactly why it failed in the first place. But this hopefully gives you enough information to figure that out.

Comment: Ok thank you. I got why it failed before. I observed that if we open registry using RegOpenEx() then by default it opens 32 -bit registry view.

Answer (score 1):

Try the sample code listed on the following help article.  It's written specifically for reading `REG_MULTI_SZ` values.

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258528

Comment: unfortunately, the sample is for Visual FoxPro